# K Nearest Neighbor in R Shiny different lengths

Tags: r, shiny, knn

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(readxl)
library(png)
library(xlsx)
library(DT)
library(class)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
normalisasi <- function(data){
((data-min(data))/(max(data)-min(data)))
}

datatrain <- read_xlsx("E:/fix/data training.xlsx")
datauji <- read_xlsx("E:/fix/data uji.xlsx")

normtrain <- as.data.frame(lapply(datatrain[,c(4,5,6,7,8,9)],normalisasi))
normuji <- as.data.frame(lapply(datauji[,c(4,5,6,7,8,9)],normalisasi))
labeldata <- datatrain[,3, drop = TRUE]
labeltarget <- datauji[,3]
prediksi <- knn(train=normtrain,test=normuji,cl=labeldata, k=input$nilaik)
hasilknn <- cbind(normuji, label=as.vector(prediksi))
output$hasil <- renderDataTable({
table(labeltarget,prediksi)
})
})
```

But I'm getting this error.

> Error in knn(train = normtrain, test = normuji, cl = labeldata, k =
>   input$nilaik)'train' and 'class' have different lengths

Whyy ? please! help

Comment: labeldata <- datatrain[,3, drop = TRUE] not use , so i change with labeldata <- datatrain[,3] not use too

Comment: please provide sample data so we can investigate